# Typescript - Pass one element of UnionType to function but not both

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have two interfaces and want to create a function where either interface A or interface B is included but not both at the same time. 
Using a simple UnionType does not work as it also allows for both interfaces to be included

Example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qgytsy)

```
interface A{
  a: string;
}

interface B{
  b: string;
}

function aOrB(modifier: A | B) {}


aOrB({ a: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ b: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ a: '',  b: '' }); // also works but should not work!
```

Is there a way to achieve this, so that the first two calls to `aOrB(...)` work but the last one not?

Br, Benedikt

Comment: One idea would be to test the input param programatically. Specifically, check if the modifier has a type A, and if it can also be of type B, throw an error.

Comment: that would work but I am seeking for a compile time solution as this function will be called by people not aware of the speciality which would then be kind of odd to throw a runtime error at them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TS type system is structural, that means `{a: 'a', b: 'b'}` is proper member of `A | B` because it is assignable to `A` as it has all `A` properties and assignable to `B` because same reason. There is no issue to use such object where `A` or `B` is required as it has all what both need in terms of structure. Consider following snippet:

```
function fOnA(modifier: A) { } // we require only A
const a = { a: '',  b: '' } // we create object with additional props
fOnA(a) // no error
```

We can do type check of type `{ a: '',  b: '' }`.

```
type ExtendsA = { a: '', b: '' } extends A ? true : false // evaluates true
type ExtendsB = { a: '',  b: '' } extends B ? true : false // evaluates true
```

As you can see `{ a: '',  b: '' }` is valid object to be used for `A` and for `B`.

> To be clear using such construct with additional properties is no harm, as we always have what we need.

The case when we want to distinct if we have `A` or `B` is a case where we should create discriminant in order to be able to check what kind of object went inside the function. 
Consider:

```
interface A{
  kind: 'A', // discriminant 
  a: string;
}

interface B{
  kind: 'B', // discriminant 
  b: string;
}

function aOrB(modifier: A | B) {}

aOrB({ kind: 'A', a: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ kind: 'B', b: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ kind: 'B', a: '' }); // error as it should be
aOrB({ kind: 'B', b: '', a: '' }); // error as it should be
```

I have added `kind` in order to distinguish both versions. Such approach has many benefits, as we can now easily check if we have `A` or `B` simply by checking the `kind`.

Another solution is to block properties we don't want by `never` keyword. Consider:

```
interface A{
  a: string;
  b?: never;
}

interface B{
  b: string;
  a?: never;
}

function aOrB(modifier: A | B) {}

aOrB({ a: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ b: '' }); // works!
aOrB({ a: '', b: ''}); // error as it should be
```

By adding `prop?: never;` I avoid allowing object to pass `A` and `B` requirements.

Comment: thank you! I have one follow up question tough with your example of `fOnA`. If I would not create a variable but put the object directly into the function `fOnA({a: '', b: ''})`, then it would also complain altough `{ a: '', b: '' } extends A` should still be true. The error message contains `"The object literal may only specify known properties"` - do you know why there is a difference?

Comment: There is a difference between putting variable and putting it directly yes, very TS specific behavior, will try to find you the resource.

Comment: `fOnA({ a: '',  b: '' } as {a: string, b: string}) // no error` as you see when you do the type assertion it works. The thing is that type inferred by TS on the level of putting it into argument directly is different. Cannot find the good resource to describe that, but its inferred not as `{a: string, b: string}`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a type which excludes certain properties:

```
type IFoo = {
  bar: string; can?: never
} | {
    bar?: never; can: number
  };


let val0: IFoo = { bar: "hello" } // OK only bar
let val1: IFoo = { can: 22 } // OK only can
let val2: IFoo = { bar: "hello",  can: 22 } // Error foo and can
let val3: IFoo = {  } // Error neither foo or can
```

Then use that type for the modifier parameter.